# How to queue aws codepipeline change sets

Tags: amazon-web-services, queue, aws-codepipeline

In a pipeline we have 3 projects bind deployed, in the first stage we retrieve all the projects, And in subsequent stages we deploy and run test on each, that will total 4 stages, 1 for getting the sources and 1 each for deployment, test and other actions. Our change release are triggered by any commit done to any of the projects in the pipeline.

Normally this works ok but apparently AWS pipeline doesn't queue the change release and can trigger one after the other if a commit is done while a change release is running, so it will run in parallel in the same instance (ec2), and subsequently generate errors.  **Is there a way to configure a queue for the AWS pipeline release change?** This discarding the option of manual approvals.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: being deployed*

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description it sounds like you have three projects in one pipeline with a stage for each project and one EC2 instance.

Why not create an independent pipeline for each project? Otherwise it sounds like you need mutual exclusion across the project stages. You could combine the three stages and let CodePipeline enforce one pipeline execution at a time occupying a stage.

I should probably mention based on your question that CodePipeline is intended for continuous delivery and it's desirable to have multiple changes moving through the pipeline at the same time. This is more obvious with deep pipelines (i.e. if it takes 3 days to fully release a change, you probably don't want to wait 3 days before a new change can start traversing the pipeline).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, so in an scenario of individual pipelines, lets say different collaborators commit code triggering multiple release changes, would those run one on top of the other by design or is it possible for those changes to be queued?

Comment: Ideally each pipeline is isolated (so no shared EC2 instance). Otherwise you need mutual exclusion across the pipelines. Could you explain why you have a shared EC2 resource a little more?

Comment: I have an image server, a back end and a front end running in the same ec2. I'm serving big files to the back end so I have them in the same instance. For the same reason the front end is in that ec2.